# How to add button on GMSMapView using swift 4

Tags: ios, dictionary, button, swift4, google-maps-sdk-ios

this is my view controller and it did not work even when i add values to CGRect

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate, 
GMSMapViewDelegate {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 52.649030, 
longitude: 1.174155, zoom: 14)
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
mapView.delegate = self
self.view = mapView

let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.649030, 
longitude: 1.174155)
marker.title = "marker1"
marker.snippet = "city"
marker.map = mapView
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
self.view.addSubview(button)

}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
 print(marker.position)
 return true
  }
  }
```

so , is there any mistakes in my code?
thank you

Comment: The CGRect is empty. Try: `UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))`

Comment: sorry I'm new this is my first question ,but still did not show the button

Comment: add  text or button background color to see the button on mapview

Comment: Brother you really need to check online tutorials first, you seem fairly new to iOS programming. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.  The button is actually there.
If you inspect the layers, you can see it in the top left corner, like so:

Simply add button title/title color. or background color and you'll see it.
[image]

```
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))

button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTap), for: .touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)

@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("You tapped a button")
}
```

After moving the button and setting title, it will look like this: 
[image]

Comment: thank you for your help i can see the button now . one more question , how can do something when the button is clicked(how i can handle this event)?

Comment: add target to button
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTap), for: .touchUpInside)
and do something with it:
    func handleTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("You tapped a button")
    }

Comment: That's how I was looking for. Thank you so much.